# Problems with module.export() in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm working into a node.js project using express.js and socketio .

Here is the problematic code (`chat.js`)

```
function chat(req, res, io) {
    chatroom = 'chatroom:' + req.params.chatroom;

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.join(chatroom);
        console.log('Join room '+chatroom);

        io.sockets.in(chatroom).emit('message', { message: 'A user just join the
             session '+chatroom });

        socket.on('disconnect',function(){
            console.log('User disconnected'); 
            socket.leave(chatroom);
        });

        socket.on('send', function (data) {
            io.sockets.in(chatroom).emit('message', data);
        });
    });

    res.render('chat.jade');
}

module.exports = function (app, io) {
    app.get('/chat/:chatroom', function(req, res){
        chat(req, res, io);
    });
};
```

My problem is that when a user go to the `chat.js` page, all pages he would consult after, the code into the `io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket)` part will be executed.

I'm pretty new to node.js world and socket.io so I don't understand why this code is being still executed whereas javascript shouldn't enter in the `chat` function first. I'm pretty sure I didn't understand something but I don't know what.

My actual project tree is the following:

```
project
├── app.js
├── models
├── routes
    ├── chat.js
├── public
├── views
```

If you have any idea, that would be great, thanks.

**Edit:** 
An example if the problem is not understandable:

First a user goes to the homepage of the project `/`, all works well, there is nothing special into the console.

Then he goes to the chat page `/chat/room1`, in console we can see

```
Join room chatroom:room1
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"message","args":[{"message":"A user just join the session chatroom:room1"}]}
```

All works fine here.

But when he goes again to the homepage, the previous message appear again in the console:

```
Join room chatroom:room1
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"message","args":[{"message":"A user just join the session chatroom:room1"}]}
```

This what I don't understand.

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: Ok I will try to give an exemple:

Comment: this probably happens because sockets.on('connection') is still set after the refresh, if you want to combine express routes with emits and other stuff from socket.io. Check out http://express-io.org/ i'm working with that right now and I can deff recommend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user goes to the home page (`/`) you obviously have the socket.io script on the page. However, it is failing to connect because socket.io is not yet listening for connections on the server.

Now when your user goes to `/chat/room1`, the following request handler handles the page request:

```
app.get('/chat/:chatroom', function(req, res){
    chat(req, res, io);
    // When this is called, socket.io starts listening for connections, but not before.
});
```

Because that request handler fired, socket.io is now listening for connections on your server. When the user again goes to `/` they still connect because now your server is listening for connections and your socket.io client-side script is present on the `/` page.

Make sure the client code is only connecting on the pages you want. Also, it's unlikely that you want to define the socket.io connection event handler within an express page route. Rather, you probably want to start socket.io listening for connections as soon as your server starts up; just make sure the client pages are not trying to make socket connections unless the user is on the desired page.

Move this code...

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.join(chatroom);
    console.log('Join room '+chatroom);

    io.sockets.in(chatroom).emit('message', { message: 'A user just join the
         session '+chatroom });

    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log('User disconnected'); 
        socket.leave(chatroom);
    });

    socket.on('send', function (data) {
        io.sockets.in(chatroom).emit('message', data);
    });
});
```

...outside of any request handlers and let it run right when your server starts up. All this code does is define an event handler that will run anytime a new socket connects to the server.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, now I understand more the correct way to implement socket.io to my projet.